# How to check the Auto Rotation orientation in Unity for Android Device?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple plugin for android. I want to set the orientation Using C# on Unity side only.

I am checking the orientation of the screen using this code.

```
if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Portrait) {
// portrait
}
else
{
// landscape
}
```

**But there is something missing in my code which I am looking for.** As there is **Auto Rotation** mode also. And I am not able to check that scenario. Can anybody help me to check the ***`AutoRotation`*** mode via Unity for Android Device.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Portrait) {
// Portrait

}
else if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown)
{
// Portrait upside down

}else if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
{
// Landscape Left

}else if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight)
{
// Landscape Right

}else if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation)
{
// AutoRotation

}
```

If you don't care about upsidedown portrait,left or right landscape, you could just do

```
    if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Portrait || Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown) {
    // Portrait

    }else if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft || Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight)
    {
    // Landscape

    }else if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation)
    {
    // AutoRotation

    }
```

The auto rotation check is included and your code is fixed to detect other rotations as well. For more information, read the Unity documentation.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenOrientation.html

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use [**Input.deviceOrientation**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-deviceOrientation.html) to check the device orientation.

And while remembering the previous state you can fire rotation events by yourself.